# Help! Activation of network connection failed ( Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: wireless, internet

I installed Ubuntu-19.04 days ago and it was working normally, today I could no longer connect via Wi-Fi, since although it detects me the Wi-Fi signals, every time I try to connect it throws me the error The activation of the connection of the connection failed net. But I can do Ethernet wiring.